# ASP.NET SiteMap - Is there a way to programatically see if it contains a page without iterating through each node individually

Tags: asp.net

Want to check that my site map contains a page.

Could just iterate through SiteMap.RootNode.GetAllNodes() but is there a way to search for a page without iterating manually?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are on the .NET Framework 3.5, you can use a LINQ method:

```
SiteMapNodeCollection pages = SiteMap.RootNode.GetAllNodes();
SiteMapNode myPage = pages.SingleOrDefault(page => page.Url == "somePageUrl");
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are on .NET 2.0 you can do something similar: put your Nodes into a (generic) list and use `Find(...)`. Along the lines of:

```
string urlToLookFor = "myPageURL";
List<SiteMapNode> myListOfNodes = new
        List<SiteMapNode>(SiteMap.RootNode.GetAllNodes());
SiteMapNode foundNode = myListOfNodes.Find(delegate(SiteMapNode currentNode)
{
    return currentNode.Url.ToString().Equals(urlToLookFor);
});

if(foundNode != null) {
    ... // Node exists
}
```

This way you do not have to iterate manually :) If this is "better" is another question.